# closure and retain cycle

Tags: swift, closures, retain-cycle

I am trying to pass a closure from one class to another.
But I am getting a retain cycle. I am new to closures and retain cycles.
I spent a couple of hours reading tutorials but I didn't understand how to do it.

I have two classes A and B. B hold an instance of A.
A has a property of type closure. B set the closure to one of his methods.
When B "clicked" B call to a method in A that uses the closure.

I know that I have a retain cycle because I am not getting the deinit prints.
My output is:

```
b clicked
b_case
from b
```

instead of:

```
b clicked
b_case
from b
Deinitialization B
Deinitialization A
```

Thanks

```
class A {
    var b_code:(()->Void)?
    var b_case = false
    func DoSomeThing () {
        if b_case {
            print("b_case")
            b_code!()
        }
        else {
            print ("other case")
        }
    }
    init () {}
    deinit {
        print ("Deinitialization A")
    }
}

class B {
    let a = A()
    let b_value = "from b"
    
    
    init(){
        a.b_case = true
        a.b_code = someCode
    }
    deinit {
        print ("Deinitialization B")
    }
    
    func someCode () {
        print(b_value)
    }
    
    func click () {
        print ("b clicked")
        a.DoSomeThing()
    }
}

var b : B? = B()
b!.click()
b = nil
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct. B is retaining A, but A is retaining as its  `b_code` property a function that refers to (captures) B. That's a retain cycle.

> I am trying to pass a closure from one class to another

No you're not. In this line

```
 a.b_code = someCode
```

the term `someCode` is not a closure. It is a method reference. That's the trouble.

Change

```
a.b_code = someCode
```

To

```
a.b_code = { [weak self] in print(self?.b_value) }
```

Or possibly

```
a.b_code = { [weak self] in self?.someCode() }
```

The point is that you must assign to `b_code` an anonymous function (what you call a closure), not a method reference, because that's the only way you can have a capture list that lets you manage the memory of the captured reference to `self` to break the retain cycle.

Comment: Your code has some other flaws but they are not what you asked about, so I won't distract you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will be glad to learn from your other comments

Comment: As a simple case in point, `b_code!()`. Why risk crashing needlessly?

Comment: thanks,
This was only for the example, but you right that I should be cearful with it